# How to delete a file from / how to delete a file

Tags: swap

I made this:

```
sudo make swap /swapfile.swap
```

because I had no swap partition.
Before that I put this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile.swap bs=4086 count=1048576.
```

The last number is wrong because I need 4Gib of swapfile. As I added to fstab a line to keep the swapfile, I eliminate it but didn't eliminate the archive to be able to change this numbers.

So system alerts me I have no space in / when before I had 44% free. So I think, to recover that space, I have to erase the archive, but I don't know with which command.

So, please, can you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sudo rm /swapfile.swap
```

to remove the file `/swapfile.swap`

Comment: I think I would modify the command slightly:  `cd /` and then `sudo rm swapfile.swap` - I hope this would prevent and accidental attemp to `rm /`